# This error appears when I run selenium script in eclipse. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

When I run Selenium script this error is appeared.

```
WARNING: Unable to obtain driver using Selenium Manager: Error running command: [C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\selenium-manager15855651361320015355641543438297284\selenium-manager.exe, --driver, chromedriver] Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20' System info: os.name: 'Windows 11'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/. The latest version can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:314)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:450)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at basics.Test1.main(Test1.java:10)
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and share your code please?

Comment: The error message you are seeing clearly states the problem: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Answer (score 0):

You have an information about error in stackTrace,
check [Chrome driver - getting started](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)
because I think you dont have configured chrome driver for Selenium as previous speaker said.